# TARGET _blank in select menu

Tags: javascript, select-menu

I want the visitors to be able to open the search form in a new tab when they selckt the checkbox.

And I have trouble getting TARGET = "_ blank" in the select menu to work.
Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.F;
var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchit.value);
window.open(submitto,'bottom');
return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.F.searchit.focus();">
<table width="100%"  border="0"><tr align="left" valign="top"><td width="200">
<form name="guideform">
In:
<select name="guidelinks" onChange="window.location=document.guideform.guidelinks.options[document.guideform.guidelinks.selectedIndex].value + document.F.searchit.value">
<option value="downloads.html?downloads=selected&amp;searchit=">Downloads</option>
</select>
</form></td>
<td><form name="F" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
Search:
<select name="sengines">
<option value="http://download.cnet.com/s/" >Download.com</option>
<option value="http://filehippo.com/search?q=" TARGET="_blank">Filehippo</option>
</select>
For:
<input name="searchit" value="" type="text" size="45">
<input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
<input type="checkbox" name="Newtab" target="_blank">New tab
</form></td>
<td width="1"></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="Newtab" target="_blank">New tab

<option value="http://filehippo.com/search?q=" TARGET="_blank">Filehippo</option>

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: You say you have trouble getting it to work so that means it must not be working, but you don't explain what is happening instead. Is nothing happening? Does an error occur? Include these details please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<option>
    <a href="http://filehippo.com/search?q=" target="_blank">Filehippo</a>
</option>
```